# android how to create e sub layout for a list of data?

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

Hi i want to create a default layout to display information and create a list of these views with buttons and strings how i can create this layout in android ? Tell me if you need better explaination

Comment: Can you please provide more detail on these ?

Comment: create a component of a form that is , not just a button but a component with strings and pics like android google drive , that every folder component is a different obj of the same class , but in one layout they have more than one buttons